# Installing Downpour bittorrent client

Tags: mac, installation, pip

I'm trying to install Downpour (http://jongsma.org/downpour/#install) on my new Macbook pro.  I am running the command "pip install Downpour", but I get the error:

```
Downloading/unpacking Twisted-Core>=8.2.0 (from Downpour)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Twisted-Core>=8.2.0 (from Downpour)
No distributions at all found for Twisted-Core>=8.2.0 (from Downpour)
```

So then I try installing Twisted by itself running the command "`pip install Twisted`" but I get the following error:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /sw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg (from zope.interface->Twisted)
Installing collected packages: Twisted, zope.interface
  Running setup.py install for Twisted
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/sw/include/python2.6 -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/sw/include/python2.6 -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
    conftest.c:1:23: error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory
    building 'twisted.runner.portmap' extension
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/sw/include/python2.6 -c twisted/runner/portmap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/twisted/runner/portmap.o
    gcc -L/sw/lib -bundle -L/sw/lib/python2.6/config -lpython2.6 build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/twisted/runner/portmap.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/twisted/runner/portmap.so
    ld: warning: in /sw/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
    Undefined symbols:
      "_Py_InitModule4_64", referenced from:
          _initportmap in portmap.o
      "_PyArg_ParseTuple", referenced from:
          _portmap_unset in portmap.o
          _portmap_set in portmap.o
      "__Py_NoneStruct", referenced from:
          _portmap_unset in portmap.o
          _portmap_set in portmap.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /sw/bin/python2.6 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/ccchen920/.pip/build/Twisted/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-5szycA-record/install-record.txt:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running egg_info

writing requirements to Twisted.egg-info/requires.txt

writing Twisted.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to Twisted.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to Twisted.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'Twisted.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

writing manifest file 'Twisted.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

running build_ext

gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/sw/include/python2.6 -c conftest.c -o conftest.o

gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/sw/include/python2.6 -c conftest.c -o conftest.o

conftest.c:1:23: error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory

building 'twisted.runner.portmap' extension

gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/sw/include/python2.6 -c twisted/runner/portmap.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/twisted/runner/portmap.o

gcc -L/sw/lib -bundle -L/sw/lib/python2.6/config -lpython2.6 build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/twisted/runner/portmap.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.6/twisted/runner/portmap.so

ld: warning: in /sw/lib/python2.6/config/libp
```

Answer (score 1):

The python you are using is in /sw so I would assume it is from [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) if so you should also install Twisted from Fink whcih will be one or more of the packages listed [here](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/browse.php?summary=twisted)

The problem you are seeing is that python was built as a 32 bit application and setuptools is trying to build as a 64 bit. This suggests that they were not installed from the same place/